# Renaming index in Titanium Alloy

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have been using Titanium for years now using Classic (even before Titanium was using eclipse or commonjs was a thing).

I am making the switch to try an app in Alloy and so far it isn't too difficult to grasp.

One thing I cannot figure out is I am not able to rename the very first view (and controller/model files) to anything other than `index`

I want my first view named `login` since my first screen will be a login screen.

I renamed the XML, TSS and JS file all to `login.*` and I get an error say no file called index was found.

I've searched and cannot find anything that answers this.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it's a requirement to have it named index.js. To work around it you can just open your login controller from the index.js

Comment: I'm just going to make my login screen the index controller. It's just weird that index is the required name and it isn't changeable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the name of the first view. The `index` controller will be fired first, you can open from there the login screen.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was not able to find that anywhere in the docs so I wasn't sure